# In quantum computing, what's the difference between the Pauli Gate and the RZ gate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, terminology, definition

I know that both rotate around the $z$-axis, but when would you want to use one over the other? What's the difference?

Comment: Am RZ gate is more general, it can rotate any angle instead of just $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

There is a relation between Pauli $\mathbf{Z}$ and $Rz(\theta)$ gate:
$$
Rz(\theta) = \mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}\mathbf{Z}} = \cos\Big(\frac{\theta}{2}\Big)\mathbf{I} - i\sin\Big(\frac{\theta}{2}\Big)\mathbf{Z},
$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is a unit matrix.

Clearly $Rz(\pi) = -i\sin(\pi/2)\mathbf{Z} = -i\mathbf{Z}$, which is $\mathbf{Z}$ up to global phase. So, if you use single qubit operation, these gates are equivalent as the global phase can be neglected.

However, controlled version of the gates behave differently as in this case the global phase of $-i\mathbf{Z}$ matters. In other word $CZ$ and $C-Rz$ are not equivalent gates.